# How to use strtol to read from an __int64 value?

Tags: c

Do exist on msvc and mingw a 64 bits equivalent function to do it ?

Aparently K&R was thinking that 2^32 was enough

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use
[_strtoi64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strtoi64-wcstoi64-strtoi64-l-wcstoi64-l) or
[_strtoui64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strtoui64-wcstoui64-strtoui64-l-wcstoui64-l).

Answer (score 7):

[`strtoll()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoll) is in C99 and POSIX.1-2001.

Comment: `long long` is int64_t in both 32bit and 64bit architectures.  Anyway, there is also an [strtoimax](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoimax).